# Which tensorflow operations trigger memory allocation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, memory, out-of-memory

Upon reading the documentation for the [TensorArray](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.12/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray.md) class, I encountered this line:

> If True, the TensorArray will be colocated on the same device as the Tensor used on its first write (write operations include write, unstack, and split). If False, the TensorArray will be placed on the device determined by the device context available during its initialization.

This makes me wonder whether only certain operations trigger actual memory allocation and reading/writing and if there is a list of those operations.

I would also like to know this as there are limitations due to OOM errors when creating tensors which are temporarily very large, but are processed in a batched manner anyways so the program is never required to actually hold all the data of the tensor - similar to how the dataset API allows processing *infinitely* large datasets as everything is loaded on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Tensorflow-GPU perspective: there is no list.

There are 2 ways TF woudl run on GPU:

- without XLA
- with XLA

Without XLA, once operation A0 is completed tensorflow would allocate the memory of all operations depending on A0: B0, B1, B2, etc. Once those are complete TF would release A0 memory as not needed anymore. If you have convolutional NN you would typically have all your forward path activations saved until backward path starts.

With XLA, multiple operations can be merged into blocks. Within the block, operations can be merged/split/duplicated to reduce memery usage. XLA cluster would have a memory management routine of it's own and it would depend on how operations have been mixed together. Multiple XLA clusters would behave as multiple non-XLA ops: they will all start as soon as possible, probably leadning to sub-optimal peak memory usage.

Comment: In my scenario, I have an operation `A` which results in a Tensor `T` which is too large to fit into memory, but before performing any _real_ operation on `T` like mathematical operations, I split it into `T0, T1, ... Tn` which fit's into memory and each part operation `Bi` consuming tensor `Ti` is run separately.

So I know that there is no need to hold the full `T` tensor in memory, but the program doesn't as upon running `B0` I get the OOM error as tensorflow can't allocate enough memory to hold `A`, so every `Bi`.

Maybe this makes it more clear.

Comment: @hechth I am not aware of any optimizations that would run operation only partially because only part of the output is in use. Therefore, I would expect TF to materialize output of A completely before doing splitting. Splitting would probably mean a memcopy of the relevant part of tensor T after which T itself can be deallocated.